# Prioritised outgoing emails using Exim

Tags: email, priority, exim, ordering, queue

Our outgoing email queue uses Exim (on Centos) and is used both for sending bulk batches of email to clients and sending authentication keys, eg as part of the forgotten password routine.  On some occasions there are already many bulk emails queued in the outgoing queue when someone requests a forgotten password authorisation link.  This email is queued with all the other emails and processed in the order received so it can sometimes be many minutes before it is sent, preventing them from completing their login.

Is there a way to add emails from the password reset process to the *start* of the queue so that they are processed immediately?